# Jboss Deployment issue

Tags: deployment, jboss

Hi guys am kinda new to the whole jboss world and i dont have a problem with jboss server its starts and stops fine but my problem is am trying to deploy 2 applications one called beaver which is connected to the other web application which is called twine-lab ,beaver is not web application but is needed for the twinelab application and i have to deploy beaver 1st before twine and i failed it send me error message with messing dependences  am working on ubuntu environment i had this task to deploy them
        Starting JBoss AS7...
``root@neuwo:/# =========================================================================

JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: /usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

JAVA: java

```
JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

10:38:18,120 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
10:38:19,166 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
10:38:19,214 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
10:38:21,077 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
10:38:21,077 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
10:38:21,089 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
10:38:21,097 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
10:38:21,170 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
10:38:21,173 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 30) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
10:38:21,175 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
10:38:21,262 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
10:38:21,262 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) JBAS016300: Activating JacORB Subsystem
10:38:21,264 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
10:38:21,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
10:38:21,387 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
10:38:21,388 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
10:38:21,615 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
10:38:21,657 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
root@neuwo:/# 10:38:22,284 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-8) live server is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration (clustered=false,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messagingjournal,bindingsDirectory=/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messagingbindings,largeMessagesDirectory=/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messaginglargemessages,pagingDirectory=/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messagingpaging)
10:38:22,358 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-8) Waiting to obtain live lock
10:38:22,364 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] (MSC service thread 1-5) Error initializing endpoint: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [98] Address already in use
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.init(AprEndpoint.java:584) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol.init(Http11AprProtocol.java:121) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]

10:38:22,460 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.connector.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.connector.http: JBAS018007: Error starting web connector
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:271)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
Caused by: LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [98] Address already in use
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:985)
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267)
    ... 5 more

10:38:22,572 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager] (MSC service thread 1-8) Using NIO Journal
10:38:22,987 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments
10:38:22,988 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar
10:38:22,991 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment beaver.ear
10:38:22,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment twine.ear
10:38:23,063 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use /84.234.78.173:9990
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.HttpManagementService.start(HttpManagementService.java:210) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:344) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:336) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:199) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:144)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:54)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:38)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:147)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.create(ManagementHttpServer.java:145) [jboss-as-domain-http-interface-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.HttpManagementService.start(HttpManagementService.java:177) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

10:38:23,065 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.remoting.server.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.server.management: JBAS017112: Address already in use /84.234.78.173:9999
    at org.jboss.as.remoting.AbstractStreamServerService.start(AbstractStreamServerService.java:109)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:344) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:336) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:199) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpServer(NioXnioWorker.java:287)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamServer(XnioWorker.java:135)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionProvider$ProviderInterface.createServer(RemoteConnectionProvider.java:209)
    at org.jboss.as.remoting.AbstractStreamServerService.start(AbstractStreamServerService.java:101)
    ... 5 more

10:38:23,064 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.remoting.server.remoting-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.server.remoting-connector: JBAS017112: Address already in use neuwo.info/84.234.78.173:4447
    at org.jboss.as.remoting.AbstractStreamServerService.start(AbstractStreamServerService.java:109)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:344) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:336) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:199) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpServer(NioXnioWorker.java:287)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamServer(XnioWorker.java:135)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionProvider$ProviderInterface.createServer(RemoteConnectionProvider.java:209)
    at org.jboss.as.remoting.AbstractStreamServerService.start(AbstractStreamServerService.java:101)
    ... 5 more

root@neuwo:/# 10:38:27,973 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager] (MSC service thread 1-8) Waiting to obtain live lock
10:39:23,066 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar")]) - failure description: "Operation cancelled asynchronously"
10:39:23,067 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015052: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period [60 seconds]. Check the server configuration file and the server logs to find more about the status of the deployment.
10:39:23,069 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015052: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period [60 seconds]. Check the server configuration file and the server logs to find more about the status of the deployment.
10:39:23,074 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015052: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period [60 seconds]. Check the server configuration file and the server logs to find more about the status of the deployment.
^C
root@neuwo:/# etc/init.d/jboss stop 
Stopping JBoss AS7...
{"outcome" => "success"}
root@neuwo:/# 10:40:49,521 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager] (MSC service thread 1-8) Live Server Obtained live lock
10:40:49,613 WARNING [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-8) Critical IO Error, shutting down the server. code=6, message=/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messagingbindings/hornetq-bindings-1.bindings (Permission denied)
10:40:49,615 SEVERE [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-8) Failure in initialisation: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messagingbindings/hornetq-bindings-1.bindings (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at org.hornetq.core.journal.impl.NIOSequentialFile.open(NIOSequentialFile.java:99) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.orderFiles(JournalImpl.java:394) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.load(JournalImpl.java:1884) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.load(JournalImpl.java:1496) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.load(JournalImpl.java:1480) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager.loadBindingJournal(JournalStorageManager.java:1500) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl.loadJournals(HornetQServerImpl.java:1548) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl.initialisePart2(HornetQServerImpl.java:1445) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl.access$1200(HornetQServerImpl.java:138) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl$SharedStoreLiveActivation.run(HornetQServerImpl.java:1919) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl.start(HornetQServerImpl.java:366) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.start(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:269) [hornetq-jms-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.messaging.jms.JMSService.start(JMSService.java:73) [jboss-as-messaging-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]

10:40:49,622 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-8) HornetQ Server version 2.2.13.Final (HQ_2_2_13_FINAL_AS7, 122) [6d4a8cda-0180-11e2-8893-d710ffcfa3d4]) started
10:40:49,625 INFO  [org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-3) Caching command for createTopic for testTopic since the JMS Server is not active yet
10:40:49,626 INFO  [org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) Caching command for createConnectionFactory for RemoteConnectionFactory since the JMS Server is not active yet
10:40:49,628 INFO  [org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-6) Caching command for createConnectionFactory for InVmConnectionFactory since the JMS Server is not active yet
10:40:49,629 INFO  [org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-2) Caching command for createQueue for testQueue since the JMS Server is not active yet
10:40:49,723 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment.connector] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010406: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
10:40:49,764 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter] (MSC service thread 1-6) HornetQ resource adaptor started
10:40:49,765 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-6) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
10:40:49,770 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment.connector] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
10:40:50,984 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.binding.jacorb (missing) dependents: [service jboss.jacorb.orb-service] 
      service jboss.binding.jacorb-ssl (missing) dependents: [service jboss.jacorb.orb-service] 
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/BeaverDS, service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/TwineDS, service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/TwineMetricsDS] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.connector.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.connector.http: JBAS018007: Error starting web connector
      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use /84.234.78.173:9990
      service jboss.remoting.server.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.server.management: JBAS017112: Address already in use /84.234.78.173:9999
      service jboss.remoting.server.remoting-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.server.remoting-connector: JBAS017112: Address already in use neuwo.info/84.234.78.173:4447

10:40:51,038 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015954: Admin console is not enabled
10:40:51,039 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 153496ms - Started 142 of 237 services (18 services failed or missing dependencies, 74 services are passive or on-demand)
root@neuwo:/# cd local/usr/
-bash: cd: local/usr/: No such file or directory
root@neuwo:/# ls
aquota.group  aquota.user  bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  sbin  selinux  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@neuwo:/# 
root@neuwo:/# ls
aquota.group  aquota.user  bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  sbin  selinux  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@neuwo:/# cd usr
root@neuwo:/usr# ls
bin  games  include  lib  lib64  local  sbin  share  src
root@neuwo:/usr# cd local
root@neuwo:/usr/local# ls
ant  bin  etc  games  gwt  gxt  include  jboss  jboss.7.1.1  jdk  jdk1.7.0_05  lib  man  sbin  share  skypekit  src
root@neuwo:/usr/local# cd jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/
root@neuwo:/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final# ls
LICENSE.txt  README.txt  appclient  bin  bundles  copyright.txt  docs  domain  jboss-modules.jar  jdbc  modules  standalone  welcome-content
root@neuwo:/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final# cd standalone/
root@neuwo:/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone# ls
configuration  data  deployments  deploymentsls  lib  log  tmp  twine-1.0.0.jar
root@neuwo:/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone# cd deployments
root@neuwo:/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments# ls
README.txt  beaver.ear.failed    mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar         mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar.redeploy  twine.ear.failed
beaver.ear  beaver.ear.redeploy  mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar.failed  twine.ear
root@neuwo:/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments# cd ..
root@neuwo:/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone# cd deploymentsls 
-bash: cd: deploymentsls: Not a directory
root@neuwo:/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone# etc/init.d/jboss start
-bash: etc/init.d/jboss: No such file or directory
root@neuwo:/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone# /etc/init.d/jboss start
Starting JBoss AS7...
root@neuwo:/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone# =========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

10:42:48,697 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
10:42:48,903 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
10:42:48,964 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
10:42:50,475 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
10:42:50,476 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
10:42:50,484 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
10:42:50,491 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
10:42:50,571 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
10:42:50,575 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 30) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
10:42:50,579 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
10:42:50,660 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
10:42:50,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) JBAS016300: Activating JacORB Subsystem
10:42:50,665 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
10:42:50,665 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
10:42:50,672 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
10:42:50,796 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
10:42:51,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
10:42:51,157 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
10:42:51,863 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-3) live server is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration (clustered=false,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messagingjournal,bindingsDirectory=/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messagingbindings,largeMessagesDirectory=/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messaginglargemessages,pagingDirectory=/usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/messagingpaging)
10:42:51,866 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-3) Waiting to obtain live lock
10:42:51,961 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-neuwo.info-84.234.78.173-8080
10:42:51,976 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager] (MSC service thread 1-3) Using NIO Journal
10:42:52,268 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /usr/local/jboss.7.1.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments
10:42:52,270 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar
10:42:52,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment beaver.ear
10:42:52,476 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment twine.ear
10:42:52,479 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017100: Listening on neuwo.info/84.234.78.173:4447
10:42:52,479 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on /84.234.78.173:9999
10:42:52,789 WARN  [org.hornetq.jms.server.recovery.HornetQXAResourceWrapper] (Periodic Recovery) Can't connect to any hornetq server on recovery [XARecoveryConfig [hornetQConnectionFactory=HornetQConnectionFactory [serverLocator=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory?server-id=0], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null], clientID=null, dupsOKBatchSize=1048576, transactionBatchSize=1048576, readOnly=false], username=null, password=null]]
10:42:52,791 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMERR: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Error trying to connect to any providers for xa recovery
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.recovery.HornetQXAResourceWrapper.getDelegate(HornetQXAResourceWrapper.java:275) [hornetq-jms-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.recovery.HornetQXAResourceWrapper.recover(HornetQXAResourceWrapper.java:77) [hornetq-jms-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:503) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:471) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.bottomUpRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:385) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkSecondPass(XARecoveryModule.java:166) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:789) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:371) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
Caused by: HornetQException[errorCode=2 message=null]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.recovery.HornetQXAResourceWrapper.connect(HornetQXAResourceWrapper.java:351) [hornetq-jms-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.recovery.HornetQXAResourceWrapper.getDelegate(HornetQXAResourceWrapper.java:251) [hornetq-jms-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
... 7 more
```

Comment: PS: You should get a firewall, you are exposing a lot of ports (21,22,25,80,110 and more) on your ip address which you included in your post.

Answer (score 5):

The key line in your console log is:

```
10:38:22,364 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] (MSC service thread 1-5) Error initializing endpoint: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [98] Address already in use
```

and

```
10:38:23,063 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use /84.234.78.173:9990
```

and

```
10:38:23,065 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.remoting.server.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.server.management: JBAS017112: Address already in use /84.234.78.173:9999
```

ETC...

Check to make sure that you aren't running more then one instance of JBoss and that you don't have other services already running on the ports listed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this post could help you:
http://www.kevinhooke.com/2012/07/25/deploymentscanner-timeouts-on-openshift-jboss-as7/

Regards,